# php encoding issue (utf8 to iso)

Tags: php

I actually got 2 pages, one is in ISO and the other one in UTF8. I have no possibility to change them without making a big mess.

There is a form in the UTF8 page that sends a GET data in Chinese characters to the ISO page.
The url looks like `search=文員` that is UTF8.

I receive the data on the ISO page and I'm not able to put it in a readable characters.

Is there a solution ?

Maybe should I transform the data on the UTF8 page in Javascript ?

Comment: ISO can mean a lot. Which ISO charset in specific? Also I suggest you migrate the ISO pages to UTF-8, this should be ok to accomplish and normalize your data-management across pages in a compatible way.

Comment: I tried once to put ISO to UTF8 when I first took this project, but it messed up all information inserted in the database, it was a mess and I needed to role back. The dev that did that didn't know that we could put utf8 in the database :-( It is ISO-8859-1

Comment: You will never be able to store Chinese characters with ISO-8859-1 into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify the sending page, add the following to your form tag:

```
<form accept-charset="ISO-...">
```

Insert the correct encoding for the second page. For more information, take a look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/form)

Comment: It worked perfectly ! Sorry I can't +1 your answer but I promise when I'll have the rights I'll +1 you :-) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Apart from giving the form an `accept-target` attribute, another option would be to convert the data on the receiving page:

```
$data = $_POST['data']; // for example
$data = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-ENCODING-HERE', $data);
```

Refer to the documentation for [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) for options that affect the behavior of the function if the input data cannot be represented in the target charset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to convert strings from your current encoding to your desired target encoding:

```
function correct_encoding($text, $target_encoding='UTF-8') {
    $current_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text, 'auto');
    $text = iconv($current_encoding, $target_encoding, $text);
    return $text;
}
```